# List iterations Python

Tags: python

Im trying to work on a popular python question - rotating a 2D list. Given a `list = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[12,13,14,15]]`.

I know a very simple solution exists which is : `zip(*list[::-1]`. But I wanted to create my own function. So i go this:

```
def flip(list):
    output = []
    temp = len(list)
    for row in range(temp):
        newlist = []
        for col in range(temp):
            newlist.append(list[col][temp - row - 1])
            print list[col][temp - row -1]
        output.append(newlist)
```

But this only works when we have an `n*n` matrix. What should I change if I have a`m*n` matrix . What am i doing wrong here

Comment: I recommend that you trace the execution (write values of temp and col) and you will see the problem!

Comment: Or use the built-in debugger, or [an interactive visualizer](http://bit.ly/1sy3MLZ), to help you trace it.

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name in Python. It is a built in function which you might need later!

Answer (score 3):

You are using `temp = len(list)` as the upper boundary for both iterations. A m×n matrix of course requires different boundaries each.

If you assume that each inner list in the outer list has the same length, you could just save both lengths first and iterate to those sizes then:

```
m = len(list)
n = len(list[0])
```

Comment: +1. And if you can't make that assumption, you can use `n = min(len(sublist) for sublist in list)` or `n = max(len(sublist) for sublist in list)` (and then appropriate code to skip over for past-end values or substitute an appropriate "fill value"), depending on what you want to do with those cases.

Answer (score 0):

Define your row and col length from the original list and then create. With some changes to your code here is something that can work for mxn. However this doesn't work if your inner lists are of not same length. zip(*list[::-1]) will give you the output using the list with minimum length. You need to make more changes for that.

```
def flip(list):
    output = []
    rowLength = len(list)
    colLength = len(list[0])
    for row in range(colLength):
        newlist = []
        for col in range(rowLength):
            newlist.append(list[col][row])
            print list[col][row]
        output.append(newlist)
    return output
```